# Backbone: Display error flash messages with errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js using rails and i have written a simple create a user piece of code. When the creation fails i want to be to present the errors in a good way in a flash message like errors in rails.

Here is my code;

```
Skymama.Views.UsersNew = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['users/new'],
  render: function() {  
    //Backbone.Validation.bind(this);   
    this.$el.html( this.template );
    return this;
  },

  events: {
    "click #user_submit" : "createUser"
  },

  createUser: function( event ){
        // validate the form        
        var firstName = $("#user_first_name").val(); //required
        var lastName = $("#user_last_name").val(); //required
        var password = $("#user_password").val(); //required
        var phoneNumber = $("#user_phone_number").val(); //required
        var emailAddress = $("#user_email").val(); //required
        var passwordConfirmation = $("#password_confirmation").val(); //required
        var dateOfBirth = $("#user_date_of_bith").val();

        //if (passwordConfirmation == password)({

            var user = new Skymama.Models.User()

            user.save({first_name: firstName, last_name: lastName, password: password, 
                        phone_number: phoneNumber, email_address: emailAddress, date_of_bith: dateOfBirth}, {
                            success: function(user, response){
                                // create flash message and render new user page

                            }, 
                            error: function(user, response){
                                //create flash message with errors and render new page
                                //alert(response.responseText);     
                                var errorView = new Skymama.Views.ErrorMessages({ el: $("#error_messages")});                       
                            }
                        });
        //});
  },

});
```

The problem is rendering a flash message with the errors. 
I have tried creating a view to display a template of the flash error.

Here is the code;

```
Skymama.Views.ErrorMessages = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST['errors/error_messages'],
    render: function() {            
    this.$el.html( this.template );
    return this;
  },
})
```

and the template;

```
<span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm tooltip-error" data-rel="popover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="<i class='icon-bolt red'></i> Top Danger" data-content="Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.">
    Top
</span>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was the simple fix needed;

```
var errorView = new Skymama.Views.ErrorMessages();                      
                                $("#error_messages").append(errorView.render().el);
```